# Will my tag score decrease if I get downvote on a post which contains that tag?

Tags: support, down-votes, tag-score

Say I have a tag score of 50 in the Java tag, and I receive one downvote for a my answer on a Java question. If the question is deleted, will my Java tag score become 49?

Comment: What do you mean by "50 java tags"? Questions or votes?

Comment: @ChrisF I meant stackoverflow tags.

Comment: You mean a score of 50 for the java tag, not '50 java tags', I think.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, I meant `50 java tags`

Comment: There is just the **one java tag**. There are no 50 java tags. You currently have a *score* of 67 for answers with the java tag, though.

Comment: In any case, *50 java tags* makes no sense in the context of Stack Exchange. You can have 50 *posts* using the tag, or you can have a *score* of 50 for posts using the tag, but there is stills just the *one* `java` tag on the site.

Comment: @MartijnPieters just raise an example, now if I get a downvote for an answer of a java question, will it become 66?

Comment: @ZhenxiaoHao: Yes, that's what I said in my answer. Your total upvotes minus your total downvotes is called your *score* for a tag.

Comment: I don't think this question is unclear at all. It's obvious what's being asked, if people just spend ten seconds to try and figure it out. Have a little more tolerance for people who are learning English and may not exactly know which words to use. /exasperated sigh

Comment: @Emrakul Thanks, there are two different answers, which one is correct?

Comment: @Zhen You may pick whichever one helps you most.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your *tag score* is the total of the number of up and down votes you received on your answers in that tag.

If you received a downvote, then your tag score goes down by 1.

If you then *delete* your answer (or the question is deleted taking your answer along) then that answer no longer counts for your tag score. This goes for *all* votes for that answer, up and down votes alike.

Say you have a score of 67, and an answer that has 2 up votes received a downvote. Now your tag score is 66. If you then delete the answer, your tag score drops to 65, as the two up votes and the one down vote no longer count.

Comment: clear enough, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, the only way for the number of tags to decrease is for all questions using a particular tag to remove that tag (or be deleted), in which case the tag will be automatically destroyed (eventually).

Comment: The OP is talking about tag score; they currently have a score of 67 for the `java` tag on Stack Overflow, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's not what the edit to his question, as well as his comment to you, indicates.

Comment: Yes, but there is a *new* comment that *does* indicate that.